# Why bundle deliver null in this code

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle

I want to deliver result from activity to fragment and I have made this code but it is not working.
I really don't know why this code is not working - actually this code is delivering null. I have no idea what should I write a code more.

This is function which send the result
-Sender activity:

```
 public void ResultTofragment(String a, String b){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence("t1", a);
        args.putCharSequence("t2", b);

        Fragment currentFragment = getFragment(FRAGMENT_ONE);

        if (args != null) {
           currentFragment.setArguments(args);
        }
    }

private Fragment getFragment(int idx) {
    Fragment newFragment = null;

    switch (idx) {
    case FRAGMENT_ONE:
        newFragment = new ExpenseCashFragment();
        break;
    case FRAGMENT_TWO:
        newFragment = new ExpenseAccountFragment();
        break;
    case FRAGMENT_THREE:
        newFragment = new EarningCashFragment();
        break;
    case FRAGMENT_FOUR:
        newFragment = new EarningAccountFragment();
        break;

    default:
        Log.d(TAG, "Unhandle case");
        break;
    }

    return newFragment;
}
```

This is the function which get the result on fragment.
-Receiver fragment :

```
public void getVoiceResult(){
    Bundle args = getArguments();

        CharSequence voiceResult01 = args.getCharSequence("t1");
        CharSequence voiceResult02 = args.getCharSequence("t2");
        //
        cost.setText(""+voiceResult01);
        explanation.setText(""+voiceResult02);
        }
```

Comment: Where do you call getVoiceResult? You should call this after the fragment was instantiated

Comment: I call getVoiceResult on that fragment , onCreate

Comment: check it for null, and only if it not null do you operations

Comment: I checked it with logcat. It doesn't get any result, if(args = null)

Comment: How are you starting your fragment from the activity? Can you share that code?

Answer (score 0):

Put your bundle value into the fragment using

```
fragmentObject.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: 'ExpenseCashFragment currentFragment = new ExpenseCashFragment();
currentFragment.setArguments(args);' I put wrote this one, it's not working neither